# Ef Core Trigrams Similarity Distance Implementation - Import Failed in EF Core PostgreSQL / npgsql

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I like to use this function- `EF.Functions.TrigramsSimilarityDistance(s1, s2)` mentioned in [this documentation](https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/mapping/translations.html). I am trying to callthis function like this-

```
string searchValue = "similar text";
var resultList = await _context.Comments.OrderBy(c => EF.Functions.TrigramsSimilarityDistance(c.Name, searchValue))
        .ThenBy(t => t.Name)
        .ToListAsync()
```

But I am seeing this error-

[image]

> DbFunctions' does not contain a definition for "TrigramsSimilarityDistance' and no accessible extension method TrigramsSimilarity Distance' accepting a first argument of type 'DbFunctions could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I am not sure how I can import the pg db extensions. What I have done is-

```
using static Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.NpgsqlServiceCollectionExtensions;
```

But it is not working.

### Update-

I am using [ASP.Net Core 3.1](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/3.1), so I am using these 2 nuget packages-

1. [Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL - v3.1.18](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL/3.1.18)
2. [Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Trigrams - v3.1.18](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Trigrams/3.1.18)

Then to configure, I have done this in **Startup.cs** file-

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => {
        options.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DevelopConnection"), option => option.UseTrigrams());
});
```

Then when I am calling like abovementioned way-

```
string searchValue = "similar text";
var resultList = await _context.Comments.OrderBy(c => EF.Functions.TrigramsSimilarityDistance(c.Name, searchValue))
        .ThenBy(t => t.Name)
        .ToListAsync();
```

And getting an error like this-

```
Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 42883: operator does not exist: text <-> text

  Exception data:
    Severity: ERROR
    SqlState: 42883
    MessageText: operator does not exist: text <-> text
    Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
    Position: 473
    File: d:\pginstaller_13.auto\postgres.windows-x64\src\backend\parser\parse_oper.c
    Line: 731
    Routine: op_error
```

Can anyone please help me to solve this problem?

Comment: What version of EF Core are you using? Have you tried getting the nuget package Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Trigrams mentionned in the documentation? EF can't find the extension method so i'm guessing there is a reference missing somewhere.

Comment: I have installed the NuGet package and then the import error is gone, but still getting this error- `Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in StartupProject-Asp.NetCore-PostGRE.dll
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware: Error: An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.

System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Term>`

Comment: It seems that in the documentation you provided you need to call the extension method UseTrigrams() on your DbContextOptionsBuilder. Are you calling this method?

Comment: No, I have to call that

Comment: Can you please add a demo answer for this question that?

Comment: Note that 6.0, the Trigrams plugin has been incorporated into the provider, so you no longer need to call UseTrigrams.

Comment: Ensure that `pg_trgm` extension is activated on your PostgreSQL server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem and written a full post on that. The full post can be found in here-

https://www.linkedin.com/posts/ajahin_sort-by-minimum-edit-distance-levenshtein-activity-6855206159448649729-dfN5/

Answer (score 0):

The first issue was because you needed to import the nuget package Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL. It seems you have you have resolved this issue.

The second issue is that the operator <-> (similarity_dist) is missing from your database. This error is thrown by the database and not Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.

You can see in [this documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/pgtrgm.html) that the operator "text <-> text" should have been installed with pg_trgm as [Svyatoslav Danyliv](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10646316/svyatoslav-danyliv) pointed out in the comments.

Here is [how to install the additional module pg_trgm](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/165300/how-to-install-the-additional-module-pg-trgm)